# make image repeat Y with unlimited scroll

Tags: html, css, image, repeat

Is it possible to make an image `repeat y` (downwards) as long as the user keeps on scrolling it keeps on repeating?

I know it's possible to repeat and image x or y but the image will stop at the end of the browser. I'm looking to make it carry on as long as you keep on scrolling down.

Preferably CSS or HTML if possible

This is what i've got to so far, I just need to know how to make the div carry on an unlimited amount:

CSS:

```
.slide {
    width:30px;
    height:1000px;
    background-image:url(http://paulbourke.net/fractals/noise/noise2d.gif);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slide"></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48k7d/)

Comment: So something along the lines of http://jsfiddle.net/48k7d/1/ ?

Comment: Not quite. Basically I want the image to repeat the same way the tounge does on this website (I apologise for the website example) http://www.mileycyrustongue.com/

Comment: I really don't understand what is the expected result

Comment: @man seems like they are using JavaScript to continually scroll the page

Comment: Look at the Script they are using some functions to getback the Scroll .. like `setInterval(checkScroll,10); function checkScroll(){    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ...`

Answer (score 1):

It's probably impossible to create HTML elements with unlimited height. However, you can use javascript to expand an element when a user scrolls near the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

With mere HTML this is (theoretically) impossible because you can wether define a absolute height and min/max height values or simply use "auto" which will automatically justify the box height depending on the size of your content.

Another (theoretical infinite scrolling) could be achieved by giving an ridiculous highabsolute height like `100000px;` But this is ofcourse not performant for the browser.

You would need some Ajax that reacts on scrollbar reaches bottom and then "append" some content to the box which  is technically invisible to the user.

You could construct something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    //- 10 = desired pixel distance from the bottom of the page while scrolling)
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
        var box = $("#myBoxId");
        //Just append some content here
        box.html(box.html() + "<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />");
    }
});
```

This way you could simulate atleast some content that is only expanding if the user scrolls to the end (or make it useful and load some content with Ajax / however...)

Ofcourse an image repeated with repeat-y will be expanded by this effect aswell.

Comment: Please don't call it "Ajax" when you're talking about Javascript. ;)